# Get series of date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want a column with date only, like this

| DATE |
| --- |
| 11/05/2022 |
| 11/05/2022 |
| 11/05/2022 |
| 11/06/2022 |
| 11/06/2022 |
| 11/06/2022 |
| 11/07/2022 |
| 11/07/2022 |
| 11/07/2022 |

And list goes on. I just want to know how to automate it like dragging from corner or some trick to make it faster without doing the manual work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this:

> =BYROW(A:A;LAMBDA(each;EDATE("11/4/2022";ROUNDUP(ROW(each)/3))))

You can change A:A to the amount of rows you need. IMPORTANT: do not use the same column than the one you want the series. If it's going to be in A1, just change =BYROW(B:B.... or else, it will create a circular dependency

And, if you start in row 3, for example, change it to B3:B, or something like that

Here, you can see it working
[image]

EDIT: another option, a little more direct and that doesn't depend on another column:

> =ARRAYFORMULA (EDATE("11/4/2022";ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(1000)/3)))

You can change that 1000 with any amount you want

EDIT 2:
If it's needed to update by one day per three rows then:

> =BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(each, Date(2022,11,4)+ROUNDUP(row(each)/3)))

Comment: day needs to be increased by one, not the month.

Comment: Ohhh, it was worth clarifying then  Try: =BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(each, Date(2022,11,4)+ROUNDUP(row(each)/3)))

Comment: Hello! I've seen my answer didn't fit you. You can change A:A with the rows you need. You can change it to A3:A if it starts in row 3, or limit until a certain row: A1:A100. Let me know either way what's that you need